# writing a microsoft word toolbar

Tags: ms-office, add-in

I want to write a Microsoft toolbar that gets a word from Microsoft Office Word and pass it to other application (Text To Speech) that is written personally. I've searched the web but not so many good ideas. First is it possible? (Sounds yes!) And is there anyone who has faced somehow the same problem? I'll appreciate any ideas.

Comment: which word version are you targeting ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Visual Studio to create a Word 2007 (or 2010) addin with a Ribbon XML file.
[MSDN has a walthough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa942955.aspx).

For 2003 or earlier, you'll need to create an addin that uses the `CommandBars` object to add a toolbar.

Comment: Thanks. I looked the page quickly it sounds exactly what I need.